# Distinct on Multiple columns in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-hive

Hi does Hive support distinct on multiple columns.
like select distinct(a, b, c, d) from table.  If not is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Yes, Please refer to following link on how to use distinct
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Select#LanguageManualSelect-ALLandDISTINCTClauses

Answer (score 10):

Yes, Hive does support distinct on multiple columns. You can do that by following

```
SELECT distinct col1, col2, col3 from TABLE
```

If you want to select distinct rows, you can use `*` instead

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM TABLE
```